# how to fix npm install && npm run dev error when compiling auth scaffolding on laravel 6?

Tags: node.js, laravel, authentication, npm-install

i'm using a virtual debian 10 server on virtualbox and a windows 10 as host. I just begin with laravel, i use the version 6, i did install it correctly but when it comes to compile the auth scaffolding using 
`npm install && npm run dev`command, it shows errors,I found similar problem in another discussion,so i tried to fix the problem on deleting the node-modules and re-run npm install as told there but it's not working. [Here is the error i got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lt68g.png).

Comment: seems like you're missing a dependency there

Comment: @GeneSy I am pretty new to all of this, how do i know which dependecy is missing? Thanks!

Comment: Make sure you have the latest node and npm installed, remove all dependencies, install again with `--no-bin-links` flag (`npm install --no-bin-links`), and if that doesn't work try with `yarn` (`yarn install --no-bin-links`)

Comment: @ka_lin thanks but it still doesn't work and keep displaying the same error, then the command you suggested `yarn install --no-bin-links` failed cause it's not among yarn option according to its output .

Answer (score 0):

This error is saying that `babel` depedencies not installed in your project. You want to install them using `npm install --dev` command.

If this method not working:-

Install these method one by one manually. This error will saying the `@babel/helper-call-delegate` module is missing. You can install it manually using `npm install --save-dev @babel/helper-call-delegate` command.

Comment: I have tried your answer but it still give me the same error.

Comment: @domodo I have updated my question. Please try again after run the suggested command.

Comment: It is still not working and the new error code is now ETXTBSY, errno -26, syscall rename, text file is busy.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when I moved my project onto a new hard drive.  Just deleting the **node_modules** folder and then running `yarn install` did the trick for me.